# How to use Xcode to design interface iosopendev?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, jailbreak

I have Xcode 4.4.1 installed on my system.
I recently installed iosopendev to develop apps for jailbreak. It integrated well, now I can see the option for iosopendev in new project menu.

My question is, how do I design the interface visually, like using storyboard for a jailbreak app, and which template should I select for that?
For starters, I selected the Cocoa Touch Library Template, but it didn't have a storyboard or xib.

I would highly appreciate it, if someone could elaborate the steps and method for designing apps for jailbreak visually using Xcode.

P.S.- I have searched a lot on the internet and didn't find anything useful and hence as a last resort posted a question here.

Comment: Just a comment ... you certainly don't **need** to use iOSOpenDev to develop jailbreak *apps*.  You can just use Xcode like you do for any other app, using the same UI design tools.  Just don't **Code Sign** inside Xcode.  I use `ldid` to fake code sign apps after building them in Xcode, and then use an internal Cydia repository on  my web server, or simple `scp` to install them on the phone.  But, I know iOSOpenDev does have some nice features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you can create UI apps in Xcode that can be used with iOSOpenDev:

**(1)** Select an Xcode template and refer to https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/wiki/Convert-to-iOSOpenDev-Project to convert it to iOSOpenDev.

..Or..

**(2)** Select an iOSOpenDev template (that produces a bundle binary), add XIB file(s), create a Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase and drag-and-drop that new Build Phase so that it is above the Run Script Build Phase that runs the `iosod` script.